# What do sentences without adjectival complements refer to?

Tags: meaning

> This event is very exciting.
>
> This event is very exciting to me.

"To me" is an adjectival complement to "exciting," so the two sentences can't be the same. However, if that's the case, what does the event excite in the first sentence? I have thought that it refers to people in general, but if the sentence is changed to past tense like in "this event was very exciting" I am not sure if it still refers to people in general or a specific group.

Comment: It's simply a way of emphasizing that you specifically are excited by it, even though others might not have found it very thrilling.  Without "to me" the statement could be taken to mean that it excited the crowd.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can something be disgusting without something else to feel disgust?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304743)

Answer (score 1):

Some indications in your question and comments lead me to think that you're taking the rule "a complement cannot be omitted" too literally. There are in fact plenty of cases where removing a complement does not really change the meaning of a sentence (at least at the level of [pragmatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics); sometimes the denotation is theoretically less precise but the context supplies the same information).

For example:

- > We're about to go eat **lunch**; you interested?

  *Lunch* here is a complement — specifically, a direct object — but *eat* can be either transitive or intransitive, and in this case the meaning remains the same even if "lunch" is removed, assuming a context in which lunch is the normal thing to go eat (e.g., a conversation among office workers around lunchtime). Of course, the speaker *could* have used a different direct object that would have provided more information ("We're about to go eat **Hunan**; you interested?"), but they didn't *need* to.
- > I don't drink **alcohol**; it gives me a headache.

  *Alcohol* here is a complement, but verb *drink* also has the specific meaning "to drink alcohol", and we can be confident that "I don't drink; it gives me a headache" would be interpreted equivalently in any ordinary conversation. (In other contexts, of course, intransitive *drink* can just mean "drink something"; for example, in a sentence like "I can't eat or drink for twelve hours before the surgery", the speaker is certainly not referring to alcohol.)

That said, it's true that "This event is very exciting" is not quite synonymous with "This event is very exciting to me"; the former does not indicate who exactly is feeling excitement, while the latter does.

A simpler analog of this would be something like *thief*, which takes an optional complement indicating what the thief steals; every jewel thief is a thief, but not every thief is a jewel thief.

Taken strictly, "this event is very exciting" only means that *someone* is feeling very excited; but in any given context, it should be clear who that someone is. For example, if the speaker is talking about an event that she herself is participating in, then she almost certainly means that *she* is very excited about it (and perhaps that other participants are, or that she assumes they are); but if she's (say) a news reporter covering an event, she very likely means only that the participants she's interviewed are excited about it. (And of course, depending on the event, it may have observers as well as participants, in which case it may be *their* excitement being referred to, whether or not the speaker is such an observer.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you would be the one doing the describing, wouldn't it be you who is excited?

Another way if of saying it is: "This event excites me."

Comment: But that would be "this event is exciting to me," and complements can't be omitted, though in a sentence in past tense like "this event was exciting" I'm not sure if it refers to people in general or just the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Whether 'To me' is an *adjectival complement* is not important. It could be an adverbial usage of a 'prepositional phrase' which indicates the subject who feels excited.

You are overthinking the prepositional phrase. You can't judge how other people would feel about an event. In other words, even if you feel excited, others might not feel the same way.

The only context that using 'to me' seems to be appropriate is for emphasis or when you compare your feeling with others', for example:

> The event was very exciting to me, but others didn't seem to like it. (They
>   didn't seem excited.)

In other contexts, 'to me' is redundant as listeners would understand without the prepositional phrase you are describing your feeling about the event. Nobody would suspect that you are referring to people in general.

Comment: Actually I think that people **would** think that you're referring to people in general - in other words that you're saying that everyone would find it exciting.  Obviously you cannot speak for everyone else, so this is "unscientific".  However, this is an example of the sort of over-generalisation which almost everybody does, all the time:  it's tolerated, basically.